# Thread cannot get the item in queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

There are two files related:
backend_service.py and web_handler.py

in backend_service.py

```
job_queue = Queue.Queue(5)

def submit_job(job):

    job_queue.put(job)
    logger.info("Enqueue new Job: JobID:%d,queue size:%d" %(job.order_id,job_queue.qsize()))

def handle_photos():
     while True:
       if not job_queue.empty():

            job = job_queue.get_nowait()
            logger.info("---------got job:%d" %job.order_id)

            print "======================I am a task================"
            job_queue.task_done()

        else:
            logger.info("the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:%d..." %job_queue.qsize())

            time.sleep(20)

worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_photos)
worker_thread.setDaemon(True)
worker_thread.start()
```

in web_handler.py  (web app based on web.py to handle the http request. The web server is uwsgi )

```
def GET():
    job = Job()
    backend_service.submit_job(job)
```

will be invoked and `job_queue.qsize` can return right value in `submit_job` function. However the thread always says the queue is empty.

It looks like the thread can not get the right status of the Queue under the web service status.  While I have test the logic using unit test . It can work correctly.
Could you please help check where I am wrong?

Comment: Where is the `job_queue` object passed into the web_handler namespace?

Comment: There is a good example here, need to pass queue object when calling thread. https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/

Comment: @dodell , web_handler.py only depends the submit_job function. and the queue is accessed in function submit_job itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your script finishes before the thread has a chance to collect any items off the queue.

In `backend_service.py`, your thread is started before anything is added to the queue, so you get *"The queue is empty..."*, the first time round.

In `web-handler.py`, I think what is happening (although I can't be sure without more code), you import `backend_service` which starts the thread and the queue,  you call `submit_job()` and then the script ends, also ending the thread before it gets a chance to look at the queue again.

If you add a delay after your job_submit call you will see that the items are taken from the queue successfully by `handle_photos()`. I've edit your code into a MCVE, including a delay after the job submission (and only sleeping for 2s between loops), and all is OK:

backend_service.py:

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

job_queue = Queue.Queue(5)

def submit_job(job):

    job_queue.put(job)
    print("Enqueue new Job: JobID:%d,queue size:%d" %(job.order_id,job_queue.qsize()))

def handle_photos():
    while True:
        if not job_queue.empty():

            job = job_queue.get_nowait()
            print("---------got job:%d" %job.order_id)

            print "======================I am a task================"
            job_queue.task_done()
        else:
            print("the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:%d..." %job_queue.qsize())

            time.sleep(2)

worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_photos)
worker_thread.setDaemon(True)
worker_thread.start()
```

web_handler.py:

```
import backend_service
import time

class a():
    def __init__(self,order_id):
        self.order_id = order_id

for i in range(3):
    job = a(i)
    backend_service.submit_job(job)

time.sleep(20)
```

Output:

```
C:\TestScripts>python web_handler.py
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...Enqueue new Job: JobID:2,queue size:1

Enqueue new Job: JobID:2,queue size:2
Enqueue new Job: JobID:2,queue size:3
---------got job:2
======================I am a task================
---------got job:2
======================I am a task================
---------got job:2
======================I am a task================
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
the queue is empty. will sleep 20 seconds:0...
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed help SiHa.  As to web_handler.py, I just simplified it. It is a web request handler based web.py.  When it's receives a HttpRequest, it will trigger the submit_job function.  At this time, you know  the thread is running and the thread should be end only we the whole web app is shut down.    As for your test result, I also get the same result.    So My  issue is that the running thread always says the queue is empty while the submit_job function can obtain the right status of the queue.

Comment: Sorry, the issue occurs under the web uswgi environment.  In the unit test script like yours, they worked well.  I am so confused.

Comment: Oh. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: WenJ, mention web uswgi environment in the question!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the new consumer thread is not in the same process with the producer one.

I am not sure the root cause,maybe due uwsgi?